# capmargin for multiline captions but centered for oneline

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, koma-script

The koma class `scrbook` centers oneline captions if not given `captions=nooneline`. However, settings setcapmargin (`\setcapmargin{0.05\textwidth}`), also one line captions are left aligned with the additional margin.

How do I have multiline captions with a fixed margin but one line captions centered?

I may use the `subfig` package, if so, I want koma to handle the captions, therefore settings `caption=false`.

Comment: Do you use the `subfig` with or without option `caption=false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "trick" is to set the caption width instead of the margin with "center" as optional position argument:

```
\setcapwidth[c]{0.9\textwidth}
```